# Unity 3d instance name conventions

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just started Unity and during a tutorial I came across this script:

```
rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
```

This is the script that controls a ship object on the screen. However, I'm used to it that objects on stage are first named, then accessed in the script. In this tutorial, the ship was simply accessed as rigidbody.

What happens if there are lots of objects like that?  How can the script distinguish?

Comment: "on stage" so you're coming from Flash? :) It's possible to get items by name in Unity, but it's not really efficient.

Comment: yes...from flash background :-) in unity it is scene..right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rigidbody` keyword will refer to *this* instance of the component. The script will need to be attached to every object you would like to modify the rigidbody of. So in other words, you should be able to find the script you are referencing attached to that ship object within the scene. Using that keyword is kind of similar to instantiating it yourself, i.e. ->

```
public RigidBody _rigidBody = null;

void Start () 
{
    _rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
}

void Update ()
{
    _rigidBody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
}
```

is the same as...

```
void Update ()
{
    rigidbody.rotation = Quaternion.Euler (0.0f, 0.0f, rigidbody.velocity.x * -tilt);
}
```

I signed up for the Unity3d classes [HERE](http://protrain.gameinstitute.com/) and it really helped me out quite a bit. Really cheap, and pretty fun stuff. :)

Comment: thanks, its much more clear now...I will look at the classes you sent me

Comment: @mirzahat Sounds good. If you don't want to dish out $50, there are also some great free resources on the Unity3d website (http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules) and all over YouTube.

Comment: The modules on unity web site are a bit too difficult IMO...all tutorials on youtube are way too long...a small game is divided into 10 tutorial modules! I need quick and dirty tutorials that will help me get a grip and feel of Unity, I dont need everything step by step...like the boring Microsoft tutorials for office...